# Shift multidimensional array left

Tags: java, multidimensional-array

i have a multidimentional array:

```
int[][] arrMulti = new int [3][3];
```

I have written a simple loop to display the data inside as a grid:

```
123
456
789
```

What i need to do now is shift everything left by one, and replace the empty gap on the right of the grid with a zero, like this:

```
230
560
890
```

Ideally i would like the method to be able to shift multidimension arrays of any size, for example

```
int[][] arrM = new int [28][28] or [98][98]
```

Can someone please help me with this?

Thanks!

This is my code so far:

```
package testingarrymove;


public class TestingArryMove {

//Start of shift array method
public static int[][] shiftArray (int arrShiftLeft[][] ) {

int from = 1;
int   to = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < arrShiftLeft.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < arrShiftLeft[0].length; j++) {    


    // move 1 to 0, 2 to 1, 3 to 2, 4 to 3, 5 to 4 ............
    System.arraycopy(arrShiftLeft, 1, arrShiftLeft, 0, arrShiftLeft.length - 1);

    from++;
    to++;

        return arrShiftLeft;
    }
}
    return null;   
} // end shiftArray

public static void main(String[] args) {

int [][] arrMultiDim = new int [3][3];

arrMultiDim [0][0] = 1;
arrMultiDim [0][1] = 2;
arrMultiDim [0][2] = 3;
arrMultiDim [1][0] = 4;
arrMultiDim [1][1] = 5;
arrMultiDim [1][2] = 6;
arrMultiDim [2][0] = 7;
arrMultiDim [2][1] = 8;
arrMultiDim [2][2] = 9;

// outputs original array
System.out.print("Original Array: ");
    //loops thought the rows of the array
    for (int i = 0; i < arrMultiDim.length; i++) {

       System.out.println();
        //loops thought the columns of the array
        for (int j = 0; j < arrMultiDim[0].length; j++) {    
            System.out.print(" "+arrMultiDim[i][j]);

        }

    }
    System.out.println();

    System.out.println("Shifted Array: "); 
    //this should copy just the row to another array by calling the shiftedArray
    shiftArray(arrMultiDim);
    //outputs the shifted array
    System.out.println(arrMultiDim);
}

} // end class
```

I have tried system.arraycopy. The above code outputs this:

```
Original Array: 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
Shifted Array: 
[[I@ece88d2
```

Answer (score 2):

At a first glance, i think the double ended queue data structure comes quite handy in this situation. You can declare a queue array with 3 rows and use queue functions for shifting left and right. For example, you might dequeue an item and enqueue 0 for a right shift, and dequeue and enqueue 0 from the other end for a left shift. You might first want to look up [the queue data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Queue_%28abstract_data_type%29) and then [the double eneded queue data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-ended_queue) and finally implement the functions or even use an existing library to use the [dequeue](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (stands for [**d**]ouble [**e**]nded **queue**) data structure. By this way, the size of the array would not matter to perform the operations as you wanted, but you have to change the data type you mentioned (3x3 array) a bit.

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void shift(int[][] arr, int offs) {
    if (offs <= 0)
        return;

    offs = offs > arr[0].length ? arr[0].length : offs;

    for (int[] row : arr) {
        if (offs < arr.length)
            System.arraycopy(row, offs, row, 0, row.length - offs);
        Arrays.fill(row, row.length - offs, arr.length, 0);
    }

}
```